# What is the meaning of these icons in Simulink?

Tags: icons, simulink

In [this document](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjABahUKEwigv9eGupTJAhWEQhQKHQOEB4U&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcn.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Fpdf_doc%2Fsldo%2Fsldo_gs.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE70YrVkvuEy9qjhUKOAiOxQatQ3g&bvm=bv.107467506,d.ZWU), I encountered following figure:
[image]

What is the meaning of the encircled icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those icons are input point and output point used when you want to Linearize your simulink model. when you are using Linear analysis tool you need to specify the input point and output point i.e  linear analysis points.

Refer the documentation
http://in.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize-simulink-model.html